# knitr + Lyx: missing the knitr->latex converter. (Rscript is in PATH, I swear!)

Tags: r, path, knitr, lyx

It's the [standard story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451581/knitr-installation-in-lyx) -- except that it persists even though I've put the R home directory in LyX's path and even in the Windows PATH environment variable. (I used cmd.exe to verify that Rscript can be called anywhere.)

Lyx 2.0.6, R-3.0.1, knitr 1.2, Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: +1 for the "I swear" :-)

Comment: and you also ran `Tools --> Reconfigure`?

Comment: @Yihui Oh yes indeed. Shoulda mentioned it. I also fiddled with User Access Control Settings to no avail.

Comment: @Yihui: I guess I was forgetting that step at the end of my frustrated thrashing, because I ran it again just now and it worked. *Something* I changed did the trick -- either fiddling with privilege elevation or putting R on the Windows PATH -- I'm just not sure what, exactly, was the crucial step. [PEBKAC](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pebkac) solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem existed between keyboard and chair (see comments).